# Get BufferedImage in two ways

Tags: java, swing

I'm curious about two swing  `BufferedImage` obtaining methods from a given and visible component.
In one way I'm painting ([`Component.paintAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paintAll(java.awt.Graphics))) component to `BufferedImage` and in second one I'm drawing image ([`Graphics.drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver))).

What's interesting is the way it behaves :

1. on draw it results in empty grey image (method `saveBufferedImageByDraw`)
2. on paint it results in proper image of component (method `saveBufferedImageByPaint`)

I would be grateful for a brief explanation.

Here is example source code (to run you need to set proper `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`) :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SaveTest extends JFrame {

    private static final String PAINT_STATUS = "Paint status : ";

    private static final String DRAW_STATUS = "Draw status : ";

    private static final File OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = new File(".....");

    private JLabel messageDraw;

    private JLabel messagePaint;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SaveTest();
            }
        });
    }


    public SaveTest() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        messageDraw = new JLabel(DRAW_STATUS);
        messagePaint = new JLabel(PAINT_STATUS);
        JButton button = new JButton("Create images");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                create(SaveTest.this);
            }
        });

        JPanel messagesPane = new JPanel();
        messagesPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Save statuses"));
        messagesPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

        messagesPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(messagesPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        messagesPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        messagesPane.add(messageDraw);
        messagesPane.add(messagePaint);

        JPanel buttonsPane = new JPanel();
        buttonsPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonsPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        buttonsPane.add(button);


        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(messagesPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(buttonsPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    /**
     * Creates the image of current component.
     *
     * @param component the component
     */
    public void create(Component component) {
        if (component != null && component.isVisible()
                && !GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()) {

            try {
                saveBufferedImageByPaint(component);
                messagePaint.setText(PAINT_STATUS + "OK");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                messagePaint.setText(PAINT_STATUS + "ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                saveBufferedImageByDraw(component);
                messageDraw.setText(DRAW_STATUS + "OK");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                messageDraw.setText(DRAW_STATUS + "ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            messagePaint.setText(PAINT_STATUS + "ERROR : invalid component state");
            messageDraw.setText(DRAW_STATUS + "ERROR : invalid component state");
        }
    }

    private void saveBufferedImageByDraw(Component component) {
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) component.createImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, component);
        g2.dispose();
        saveImage(image, "DRAW");
    }

    private void saveBufferedImageByPaint(Component component) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();     
        component.printAll(g2);
        g2.dispose();

        saveImage(image, "PAINT");
    }


    public static void saveImage(BufferedImage image, String prefix) {
        try {
            File f = new File(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, prefix + ".png");
            ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, component);` does not really do anything useful - `g2` belongs to the image, so you're drawing an (empty) image on top of itself.

Comment: Kiheru, thanks for details. So to use `drawImage` method to obtain `BufferedImage` of my component I have to use `g2` i.e. of parent component? Am I right?

Comment: The component does not exist as an image (what you see on screen is just what the component happened to paint on a temporary buffer), so when you need an image, you need to create it by yourself. Using `printAll()` is correct. (`paintAll()` works too, and the difference between those is barely documented; and in fact they end up running the same code by default. `print*` is the recommended way for painting to off screen buffers though).